# declarations in css empty selector not functioning for div class

Tags: html, css

I have some styling for comments. However if the server sends null the div tag is going to require a different (no) styling.

What's the best way to do this in CSS (preferably)? Such as is there a way to do *not* empty in CSS ???

```
<div class="comments"><?php echo $comment; ?></div>


.comments{
    color: #CD3134;
    padding: 10px;
    float: right;
    border-style: dashed;
    border-color: #FF0000;
    width: 200px;
}
.comments:empty{
    border-style: none;
    border-color: none;
    clear:both;
}
```

Comment: So you're saying if $comment is empty, you don't want to apply the styling you have to .comments? Just remove the leading space in front of the php tag.

Comment: It is unclear what you mean by “empty” and how “empty” comments should be rendered. The code in the example produces an element that always contains at least one character, a space, so it is never empty in the sense of matching `:empty`. If you remove that space and the element becomes really empty, should it still be rendered as a visible block, just empty and without borders?

Comment: looks like I had a few problems here, thank you for picking up on the character space. Also my declaration was bad. Needs:  border-style: none; Lastly  I read on w3 schools that :empty selector only works with p elements. Which I am guessing is wrong. @JakeParis gave two good answers here below. I would probably fix this server side since the empty selector is not good with older browsers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you can negate the `:empty` pseudo selector with the following:

```
.comments:not(:empty) { }
```

Another way would be to add a class to the div if there are no comments.

```
<?php
$commentclass = $comments == '' ? 'nocomments' : '';

<div class="comments <?php echo $commentclass; ?>"> <?php echo $comment; ?></div>

.comments{
    color: #CD3134;
    padding: 10px;
    float: right;
    border-style: dashed;
    border-color: #FF0000;
    width: 200px;
}
.comments.nocomments{
    border-style: none;
    border-color: none;
    clear:both;
}
```